# Can't Import 'Echo' from Module : Uncaught ReferenceError: Echo is not defined

Tags: javascript, laravel, class, export, laravel-echo

I am testing the laravel/redis/socket.io messaging capabilities. During the process of initial setup I have noticed that echo.js, both the version from NPM as well as "compiled" to a module from GIT causes the error. 
**"Uncaught ReferenceError: Echo is not defined"**

I am stumped because it technically should work, any help?

1) i have used out of the box echo.js 
2) I have build a js package out of the GIT laravel-echo TypeScript repository
3) I have checked that the scripts are loading

```
window.Echo.channel('everywhere')
    .listen('AnnouncementEvent', (e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });
```

I would like to find out what am I missing on a solution that should work and have the echo.js start working in tests

Comment: Furthermore - when loaded inline the JS message states that the module does not contain the specified "Echo" object to import ...
**<script type="module">
console.log('loading module Echo.');
  import { Echo } from 'http://echo.js';
</script>**

Comment: you import Echo in bootstrap.js file?

Comment: Yes... it is getting to the browser (the echo.js data - its visible on the traffic waterfall) however the browser does not Import "Echo" - or so it would seem ..

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my issue ... I am not sure it it is the correct analysis and resolution however it works.

With laravel **`echo`** distro come three distinct `echo*.js` files:

**`echo.js`** - a `ES5-ES6` module that does not work in browser even if imported with `type='module'` set

**`echo.iife.js`** - a browser compatible version of the library

**`echo.common.js`** - a `nodejs` commonjs module

I had found I have to include `echo.iife.js` in order for this Javascript **`Echo`** class to register properly in browsers and be exposed to scripts.

Comment: You don't need to include any of the echo js files if you use mix/webpack to compile it into your main js file like it says in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a few puzzle pieces here...

Install predis `composer require predis/predis`

Install a socket.io server like this one, https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server

Install socket.io client library `npm install --save socket.io-client`

Instantiate Echo in your boostrap.js file:

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"

window.io = require('socket.io-client');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ':6001'
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/broadcasting

Comment: I am sure that will be helpful to someone with a similar however I had socket.io included .. I will post the reason in answer...